# GeoServer - Authentication for external WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms, authentication, token

I am adding layers from several external WMS sources.  Some of them use authentication and when I for example add &token=mysecret to the getCapabilities request, then this token is also added to the URL's in the getCapabilities and all works fine when I use the layers.

But, one of the sources does not include the token in the getCapabilities so I need to add that to the store/layers.

Another source use oauth2 with bearer token.

There is a module to add authentication for the layers GeoServer are publishing, but I found no info or modules on how to use authentication requesting external sources.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That seems to be a missing feature in GeoServer https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html. Only basic authentication with user/password is supported. Especially "Extra request parameters (time, elevation, cql_filter, etc.) cannot be used" which prevents adding `&token=mysecret`. Certainly support for tokens could be added.

Comment: If you can add `&token=secret` to the capabilities request (and it then appears in the capabilities document) it can be used that way. But general authentication is definitely a missing feature - it would be great if someone(s) could contribute the code or sponsor the work.